# Compiling a minimal C++ program with implicit rules using Make

Tags: c++, makefile, compiler-errors, g++

This [article](https://makefiletutorial.com/) shows the following example for compiling a minimal C program with implicit rules using `make`.

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g

blah: blah.o

blah.c:
    echo "int main() { return 0; }" > blah.c

clean:
    rm -f blah*
```

When I attempt to run this using `make blah` it seems to work fine and outputs an executable with the following being logged in standard output:

```
$ make blah
echo "int main() { return 0; }" > blah.c
gcc -g -c -o blah.o blah.c
gcc blah.o -o blah
```

I tried to adapt this for a minimal C++ program, and came up with the following Makefile:

```
blah: blah.o

blah.cc:
    echo "#include<iostream>\nint main() { std::cout << 123 << std::endl; }" >> blah.cc

clean:
    rm -f blah*
```

When I try `make blah, I run into an error:

```
echo "#include<iostream>\nint main() { std::cout << 123 << std::endl; }" >> blah.cc
g++    -c -o blah.o blah.cc
cc   blah.o   -o blah
/usr/bin/ld: blah.o: warning: relocation against `_ZSt4cout' in read-only section `.text'
/usr/bin/ld: blah.o: in function `main':
blah.cc:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `std::cout'
/usr/bin/ld: blah.cc:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(int)'
/usr/bin/ld: blah.cc:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)'
/usr/bin/ld: blah.cc:(.text+0x2a): undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))'
/usr/bin/ld: blah.o: in function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
blah.cc:(.text+0x61): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
/usr/bin/ld: blah.cc:(.text+0x7c): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
/usr/bin/ld: warning: creating DT_TEXTREL in a PIE
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [<builtin>: blah] Error 1
```

It seems to me that `make` is still running a `cc` command, which I suspect is why the error occurs.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

On my system, the implicit rule for producing programs is:

```
%: %.o
        $(LINK.o) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

where

```
LINK.o = $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH)
```

Check for yourself with `make -np -f/dev/null`.

You can either solve the problem by changing `LINK.o` to use `$(CXX)`, or adding a recipe to the `blah` rule.

Answer (score 0):

C object files need to be linked with cc while C++ objects files need to be linked with c++ if you expect all the required libs to automatically included. Since the name for both is the same there can only be one automatic rule to link a binary. The default rule is to link C object files.

You can set `CC = $(CXX)` to change what the default rule uses to link.

Comment: Are you sure this actually works? From my answer it looks like `$(LD)` is not consulted.

Comment: @Botje You are right. the default rule uses $(CC) to link. Odd, I thought it used $(LD).